# How to solve the "String or binary data would be truncate" in java?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, servlet-3.0

I created a table for file I put the datatype for file varbinary(MAX) and when I am trying to upload the file it show me:

```
String or binary data would be truncated
```

When I wrote insert query like this:

```
   String sql = "INSERT INTO contacts (first_name, last_name, photo) values (?, ?, ?)";
   PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
   statement.setString(1, firstName);
   statement.setString(2, lastName);

   if (inputStream != null) {
       // fetches input stream of the upload file for the blob column
       statement.setBlob(3, inputStream);
   }
```

I tried setBinaryStream too but it still gave me same error so please help me how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The error means that your binary data will be truncated when saving the data in a `VARBINARY(MAX)` column. Just change the type of your column to [`BLOB`](http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/definition/BLOB).